# JavaCV example is not working - what am I missing?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

It's the first day of learning JavaCV for me. And this is the first test example which I use just to make sure that my setup is done correctly. Unfortunately I can't run the example and I barely understand the code and all dependencies so it's really hard for me to find out what is missing. Below I'll post my project setup and also the errors I get.

Also the example I use is from: http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/javacv-capture-save-flip-show-live.html

**code**

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvFlip;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class GrabberShow implements Runnable
{
    //final int INTERVAL=1000;///you may use interval IplImage image;
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
    public GrabberShow()
    {
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0); // 1 for next camera
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img;
            while (true)
            {
                img = grabber.grab();
                if (img != null)
                {
                    cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
                    cvSaveImage((i++) + "-aa.jpg", img); // show image on window
                    canvas.showImage(img);
                }
                //Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I use `Eclipse` and it seems like all imports are there.

Here is a print screen of my project as it looks like in `Eclipse`:

[image]

So this is it for the setup. I try to get something out of this. When I right click on the project and try to `Run` it as `Java Application` the following windows is showing up:

[image]

You can see my choice at the top of the window. The I get an error window `A Java Exception has occurred` and here is part of the error I get in the console window:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Xman\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp4929678155627\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:422)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:372)`
```

I've read the error, it seems like the problem is caused by missing libraries but I'm not sure, also I have followed the instructions (which weren't that many in fact) and from the comments below the example code it seems that it actually works. So I guess the problem is somewhere here - in my project, code, setup, but I can't find what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711088/javacv-unsatisfied-link?rq=1

Comment: @RC thanks for the reference but to be honest it wasn't of much help. Also I hope that my question is well formatted to help people who have experience with JavaCV to easily read and eventually find what is wrong with my code which is not the case with the example you suggest (formatting is awful I can't understand a single line of what he has written).

Comment: It seems you are missing some DLL, your library uses a native library....

Comment: It's my first project using so many external libraries so I do believe the problem is somewhere there, but I don't know how to detect it. Also, I thought that following the example will protect me from problems like this and even now I'm sure if the problem is really in the libraries cause I import everything mentioned in the tutorial or at least I'm pretty confident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when your opencv dll are not set in System path.
If you have extracted your opencv folder in C:\ directory then set your path as following

For 32 bit:

```
C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin;C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10\
```

For 64 bit:

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin;C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc10\
```

If you have extracted in different location then change the path accordingly.

In order to set path you can go to Control Panel > System Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables. In System variable select path and click on Edit and insert above locations and restart windows.

you can find detailed instructions at http://opencvlover.blogspot.in/2012/04/javacv-setup-with-eclipse-on-windows-7.html

Comment: I've just added the paths but I still get the same error. My install location of `OpenCV` is `C:` and maybe it's a step further ahead, but I guess there something more I need to do. In the main post you can see the `Select Java Application` window that I get with several options. When I choose a different option I get a different error, so I think I should make something there too, not sure what exactly though, but still, thanks for the advice. But I'll leave the question open for a while now, because I still haven't solved my issue.

Comment: The code you have provided implements Runnable. So you have to write a test code in order to run it. Look at the blog link you have posted. there is a test code at the bottom of post. Or instead you can also use main function directly as described at http://opencvlover.blogspot.in/2012/05/accessing-webcam-using-javacv.html

Comment: Hi nikhil I've just tried the code from the link you posted above. Now I get my canvas on the desktop but there are just the 3 system buttons - minimize, maximize, close, and I get a system error in the console which is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Xman\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp21738767915013\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries` . I don't have folder named `AppData`, and I'm not sure if it's created automaticly or I missed some step, but I think you're leading me on the right way so do you have any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Just to make it clear for the others - it was that I had both versions of `Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package` so when I uninstalled the `x86` (because I'm with 64bit OS) everything else goes on smooth. The example that `nikhil` have shared in the comments is perfect for beginners. So thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Leron I spent all day on this problem! I had Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package installed in both x86 and 64 bits. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Download and install : Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package (32-bit):  [vcredist_x86.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555)

Comment: I have them installed from before I checked my Control Panel just to verify that.